# Why torrent peer sends an empty messaage?

Tags: python, tcp, bittorrent

**Short problem description**

```
request0 = "001360000000000\x400"  # Requesting for piece number 0
s.send(request0);
receivedPiece0 = s.recv(16384);
print len(receivedPiece0);  # prints 0
```

The message I receive back is empty. Why?

**Longer problem explanation**

I am trying to write a BitTorrent client, and am now stuck on the part, where
after receiving `unchoke` message I need to send requests for downloading file pieces. After every request I get an empty message back.

After handshaking and sending `interested` message, the first message
I received was:

```
# _ characters are just added by me in this post for  clarity,
# they were not present in the message
000250______000540001_______000540002_______000540000_________00011
bitfield    have piece 1    have piece 2    have piece 0      unchoke
```

Then I sent the request to get piece 0:

```
request0 = "001360000000000\x400"  # asking for block size of 2^14
s.send(request0);
```

and got the reply back:

```
receivedPiece0 = s.recv(16384);
```

previously the last line throwed timeout error, because my request was
incorrectly formed. Now I get an empty message back. Why?

Comment: are you using nonblocking IO? if so you need to use an event-based API that notifies you when data actually becomes available.

Comment: I think I use blocking IO: python s = socket.socket(...); s.settimeout(2)
If s.recv() is still nonblocking event, how to make event-based api then? Or perhaps polling would work here?

Comment: I guess it's blocking but with a finite timeout? So if it doesn't get any data after 2 (seconds? milliseconds?) then the call returns without data.